# What is p-adic topology on $\Bbb Z$?

Tags: general-topology

What are the ((sub)base) open sets in the $p$-dic topology on $\Bbb Z$?

$p$ is a prime number.

Comment: Define the $p$-adic topology.

Comment: @k.stm I assume it's the subspace topology on $\mathbb Z$ under the topology on $\mathbb Q$ induced by the [$p$-adic norm](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/p-adicNorm.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a *metric* space, given by the metric

$$d(x,y) = \|x-y\|_p = p^{-k} $$

where $k$ is the largest integer such that $p^k$ divides $x-y$.

In general, an open basis for the topology corresponding to a metric is the sets

$$B(x, r) = \{ y \mid d(x,y) < r \}$$

In algebraic terms, this basis is precisely the collection of all cosets of the form $a + p^k \mathbf{Z}$. Note, incidentally, that all of these sets are both open *and* closed.

Comment: Do you  mean all sets of the form $x + p^k \Bbb{Z}$ with $k$ an arbitrary positive integer?