# Example of topologies generated by metric such that the union is not a topology?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I was going through the following exercise : $\cup_{\alpha \in \Lambda}\tau_{\alpha}$ is not a topology.

$\tau_1=\{\{\phi\},\{a,b\},\{c\},\{a,b,c\}\}$

$\tau_2=\{\{\phi\},\{a\},\{a,b,c\}\}$

Let $U_1=\{c\}$,$U_2=\{a\}$.

Then $U_1 \cup U_2 =\{a,c\}$ is not an open set.

My doubt is tht can we get an exanple of  topologies generated by metric such that the union is not a topology?

Comment: Let $A,B$ be disjoint non-empty spaces (metrizable or not) with topologies $T_A, T_B.$ Then $U=T_A\cup T_B$ is not a topology because $A\in U$ and $B\in U$ but $A\cup B\not\in U.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p$ and $q$ be two distinct prime numbers. Then the [$p$-adic metric](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/798892/what-is-p-adic-topology-on-bbb-z) and the $q$-adic metric on $\Bbb N$ are examples of topologies whose union is not a topology.

Indeed, $p\Bbb N$ is open in the $p$-adic topology, $q\Bbb N$ is open in the $q$-adic topology, but $p\Bbb N \cup q\Bbb N$ is not in the union of the two topologies.